# When a sphere is in pure rotation, will all particles in its surface have same linear speed?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

Imagine this sphere to rotate about its diameter, from the centre to the point of surface if we take all of them have equal distance that is 'r(radius of the sphere)'.So same linear speed right? I looked up many sites but they all say "The linear speed v = ɷr. That means the particles at different r will have different linear speed".I am not able to digest it. Can anyone please make me understand in a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linear speed of a point on a rotating object will depend on the angular speed and distance between the point and the *axis of rotation*. All points on a sphere are equidistant from the center of the sphere, but are not equidistant from an axis of rotation through the sphere. Consider the earth spinning about its axis - the poles have no linear movement whatsoever (they simply spin in place), while points on the equator are moving at 460 m/s in order to complete their 40,000km rotational circuit once every day.

Answer (score 1):

The distance to be considered is axial. You have various slices wich give different circumferences (varying radius) with a maximum at the equator.
Take for instante a cylinder: then you have only one axial radius. But the sphere has different level curves